# How to use "skipFailedInvocations" and "retryAnalyzer" using testNG?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

How do we use `"skipFailedInvocations"` and `"retryAnalyzer"` with **`@Test`** Annotation using testNG?

Request you to provide an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Example code:**

***Demo test class:***

```
public class DemoClass{

@Test(skipFailedInvocations=true, retryAnalyzer=RetryAnalyzer.class)
public void test(){
    Assert.assertTrue(false);
}
```

}

***Retry Analyzer class:***

```
public class RetryAnalyzer implements IRetryAnalyzer  { 
private int count = 0; 
private int maxCount = 4; // set your count to re-run test

public boolean retry(ITestResult result) { 
        if(count < maxCount) {                     
                count++;                                    
                return true; 
        } 
        return false; 
}
}
```

**Explanations:**

If the value for skipFailedInvocations is set true and invocation count (here maxCount in the RetryAnalyzer class) is > 1, then all invocations after a failure will be marked as a SKIP instead of a FAIL.

Comment: Oh yea! Thank you. I made a small mistake. It worked now.